# embed audio records from Twilio Call logs to my website and stop getting 401 UNAUTHORIZED and Userlogin https://api.twilio.com

Tags: php, twilio

How to embed audio records from Twilio Call logs to my website?

And I get https://api.twilio.com Sign in dialog box... and 401 UNAUTHORIZED when loading the tables

ViewCall function:

```
    $accountSid    = "ACXXXXXXXX";
    $authToken  = "XXXXXX";
    $twilio = new Client($accountSid, $authToken);

    $call_logs = $twilio->calls
                    ->read();       

    $data=array();
    foreach ($call_logs as $call_log) {

        $data[]=array(
            "sid" => $call_log->sid, 
            "from" => $call_log->from,
            "to" => $call_log->to,
            "duration" => $call_log->duration,              
            "status" => $call_log->status,
            "direction" => $call_log->direction,
            "uri" => 'https://'.$accountSid.':'.$authToken.'@api.twilio.com'.$call_log->uri
        );
    }   
    return $data;
}
```

And in my view..

View.php

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="getCall in getCalls">
       <td>{{ getCall.direction}}</td>
       <td>{{ getCall.from }}</td>
       <td>{{ getCall.to }}</td>
       <td>{{ getCall.duration }}</td>
       <td>
          <audio controls> <source v-bind:src="getCall.uri" type="audio/ogg"> </audio> 
       </td>
       <td v-if="getCall.status == 'delivered'">
           <b-btn class="btn btn-pill btn-sm btn-info btn-block">{{ getCall.status }}</b-btn>
      </td>
       <td v-else="getCall.status =='received'">
          <b-btn v-if="getCall.status == 'completed'" class="btn btn-pill btn-sm btn-success btn-block">{{ getCall.status }}</b-btn> 
          <b-btn v-if="getCall.status == 'busy'" class="btn btn-pill btn-sm btn-warning btn-block">{{ getCall.status }}</b-btn>  
          <b-btn v-if="getCall.status == 'no-answer'" class="btn btn-pill btn-sm btn-danger btn-block">{{ getCall.status }}</b-btn>
         <b-btn v-if="getCall.status == 'failed'" class="btn btn-pill btn-sm btn-danger btn-block">{{ getCall.status }}</b-btn>
      </td>
   </tr>
```

In my script

```
 axios.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";
       this.loading = true
      axios
        .get("api/view-call")
        .then(response => {
          this.loading=false;
          this.getCalls = response.data;
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e.response);
        });
```